# Logging in/out of Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: login, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I hit `Ctrl-D` in WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) and the window closed. Now when I try to re-enter WSL, I get a blank window with a flashing cursor and nothing else. `Ctrl-C` closes the window, and `Ctrl-F` pops up a Windows "Find" window; nothing else registers. How do I resurrect WSL?

**Update** Win10 was doing an update at the time, so once that was complete I had to reboot the computer. WSL opened fine, so I thought all was well. I should have tried closing and reopening it at that time, but I didn't. Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Comment: Check if windows is currently installing an update. Restarting Windows should help. Ctrl+D is a perfectly valid way to exit WSL, it should not be happening

Comment: Thank you, Carlos. It was installing an update. If you would change your comment into an answer, I'll mark it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am sometimes afraid to put an answer where my solution is not a direct fix for the question, to avoid negative points. ;-)

Comment: Carlos, I understand.

Comment: What happens if you kill the process init in the Windows task manager?

Comment: Variable results. The first few times worked, but not at the moment.

Comment: You can try reseting your distribution in App Settings. Are you using an Insider version?

Comment: I'm not using an Insider version. I didn't realise there are settings in "Apps & features". Under "Reset" I've clicked the first option, "Repair". It's working for the moment. If I have any further problems, I'll try that again. I see there's also a "Reset" option below "Repair". If ever it gets to the point when even that doesn't work, I'll use the "Uninstall" option and then re-install. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: You can completely restart wsl by running `wsl --shutdown` (at least wsl 2)

Comment: Thanks, @dan1st. I'm in the middle of backing up my hard drive right now, but I'll definitely give that a try when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Check if Windows is currently installing an update. Restarting Windows should help.

Ctrl+D is a perfectly valid way to exit WSL. It should not be happening.

Sometimes killing the *init* process will help to start a new WSL session cleanly.

Regards

Comment: Carlos, unfortunately I have to uncheck your answer because the updates completed and the problem still there. It runs fine the first time after I reboot, but closing it and trying to reopen it doesn't work. Sorry :-(